# Can the constructor of a derived class have more parameters than the constructor of its base class?

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, constructor

I have a base class and 2 derived classes. The base class has a few simple protected float variables and the constructor for my base class is as follows:

```
public Enemy(float _maxhp, float _damage)
{
    maxhp = _maxhp;
    health = _maxhp;
    damage = _damage;
}
```

However, my derived class `Range` has 2 more float variables `attack and attackSpeed` that need to be passed in as arguments when creating a new instance of `Range` but I can't seem to be able to do that since an error saying `There is no argument that corresponds to the required formal parameter '_maxhp' of 'Enemy.Enemy(float, float)'` when I try to use a constructor for the derived class with these params:

`public Range(float _maxhp, float _damage, float _attack, float _attackSpeed)`

but a constructor with the same number of params works

`public Range(float _maxhp, float _damage)`

Why is this happening and is there some kind of workaround? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure. All objects inherit from object which has no constructor parameters, so the fact that some objects have constructors to with more than one parameter proves it can be done. (You just need to chain it to base(...) if the base class does not have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: In fact a derived class can even have fewer arguments in it's constructor as long as it passes something to the base constructor.

Comment: Could you provide an example of that? @juharr

Comment: Thinking about a square derived from rect. Rect has two argument height and width But Square has one.

Comment: Also, if my base constructor has no params but it does something and i want my derived constructor to call that something as well, do I just put

`public Range() : base()`

as the constructor for my derived class or is there no need to?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to specify how to call the constructor on the base class using the `base()` constructor call:

```
public Range(float _maxhp, float _damage, float _attack, float _attackSpeed)
    : base(_maxhp, _damage)
{
    // handle _attack and _attackSpeed
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try this-

```
public Range(float _maxhp, float _damage, float _attack, float _attackSpeed) : base(_maxhp, _damage)
{
this.attack = _attack;
this.attackSpeed = _attackSpeed;
}
```